# Discord bot Python, exceptions for administration

Tags: discord.py

I have a small problem, please help me solve it.I created anti-caps,anti-links,and a blacklist of words.The problem is that all these systems affect me and the other administrators.How do I add adminstrators to bot team exceptions?

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.isupper() and not message.author.bot and len(message.content) > 4:
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await message.channel.send('Do not use caps!')
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if message poster equals an admin username and if so don't apply these restrictions ex.

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != 'your username':
        if message.content.isupper() and not message.author.bot and len(message.content) > 4:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
            await message.channel.send('Do not use caps!')
    ```
````

For more usernames you can create an array and check if message.author is in that array

Answer (score 0):

The permissions that the author sent the message can be retrived by `message.author.permissions_in` method. It takes channel object as parameter and returns a list of permission objects so you only need to check whether the Administrator's permission is in it. Alternatively, The roles that the author sent the message are stored in `message.author.roles`. It's just a list with Role objects so you can check if Administrator's role is in it.